# How to redirect YouTube's videos URL (googlevideo.com) from HTTPS to https automatically?

Tags: firefox, video, youtube, https, https-everywhere

I am using FireFox on Linux and I want to redirect HTTP URLs in YouTube videos to HTTPS. YouTube’s videos are from `googlevideo.com` so I want to use HTTPS instead of HTTP:

```
http://r8---sn-qxau5-btqs.googlevideo.com...
```

To:

```
https://r8---sn-qxau5-btqs.googlevideo.com...
```

(`r8---sn-qxau5-btqs`) may change with every video URL.

I tried HTTPS Everywhere and made this rule:

```
<ruleset name="googlevideo">
<target host="*.googlevideo.com" />

<rule from="http://([^@:/][^/:@])\.googlevideo\.com/" to="https://$1.googlevideo.com"/>
</ruleset>
```

But it doesn’t seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2015, all Youtube videos are served through HTTPS by default.

[image: Firefox console screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to download and install the plugin called [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere). It will force all websites into secure mode. If it is available.